# Maximum Pseudo-Likelihood estimator for soft-core point process

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, point-process

I am trying to fit a [soft-core point process model](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spatstat/versions/1.56-1/topics/Softcore) on a set of point pattern using maximum pseudo-likelihood. I followed the instructions given in this [paper](http://wildfire.stat.ucla.edu/pdflibrary/baddeleyturnerpseudo.pdf) by Baddeley and Turner

And here is the R-code I came up with

```
`library(deldir)
 library(tidyverse)
 library(fields)

 #MPLE

 # irregular parameter k

 k <- 0.4

 ## Generate dummy points 50X50. "RA" and "DE" are x and y coordinates


dum.x <- seq(ramin, ramax, length = 50)
dum.y <- seq(demin, demax, length = 50)
dum <- expand.grid(dum.x, dum.y)
colnames(dum) <- c("RA", "DE")

## Combine with data and specify which is data point and which is dummy, X is the point pattern to be fitted

bind.x <- bind_rows(X, dum) %>%
mutate(Ind = c(rep(1, nrow(X)), rep(0, nrow(dum))))

## Calculate Quadrature weights using Voronoi cell area

w <- deldir(bind.x$RA, bind.x$DE)$summary$dir.area

## Response
y <- bind.x$Ind/w

# the sum of distances between all pairs of points (the sufficient statistics)

tmp <- cbind(bind.x$RA, bind.x$DE)
t1 <- rdist(tmp)^(-2/k)
t1[t1 == Inf] <- 0
t1 <- rowSums(t1)
t <- -t1

# fit the model using quasipoisson regression

fit <- glm(y ~ t,  family = quasipoisson, weights = w)
`
```

However, the fitted parameter for `t` is negative which is obviously not a correct value for a softcore point process. Also, my point pattern is actually simulated from a softcore process so it does not make sense that the fitted parameter is negative. I tried my best to find any bugs in the code but I can't seem to find it. The only potential issue I see is that my sufficient statistics is extremely large (on the order of 10^14) which I fear may cause numerical issues. But the statistics are large because my observation window spans a very small unit and the average distance between a pair of points is around 0.006. So sufficient statistics based on this will certainly be very large and my intuition tells me that it should not cause a numerical problem and make the fitted parameter to be negative.

Can anybody help and check if my code is correct? Thanks very much!

Comment: Did you try to reproduce your results directly with the `spatstat` package?

Comment: @EgeRubak I tried using `ppm` with softcore interaction. The parameter for simulation is $\log(\beta) = \log(6000) = 8.699$ and $\sigma = 0.0065$. The fitted parameter from the simulated data is $\log(\beta) = \log(4307) = 8.37$ and $\sigma = 0.0067$. So my data is not wrong. But I really can't seem to find any mistakes in my code.

Comment: Not by my computer so can't offer detailed help. You both divide by weights in `y` and use weights in `glm`. Is that correct? In general my best advise is to reproduce the `spatstat` results as closely as possible. Make a quadrature scheme in `spatstat` and extract the coordinates and weights and use them in your call to `glm`. You can find a bunch of glm info deep inside the list returned by `ppm` maybe that could help with debugging also. Let me know how it goes... Also think about edge correction when trying to reproduce results...

Comment: @EgeRubak Dividing `y` by weights and using weights in `glm` is just me following the procedure from the paper as I understood it and I tried removing division or removing weights, it still gives me negative values. For the edge correction, I think it might not affect the results that much as to make the fitted parameter negative since I used border correction of 0.0001 (which is very small compared to the whole observation window) in `ppm` and the results from the last comment was what I got. I will try to look into the results returned by `ppm` and see how it goes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The procedure described in the paper is implemented in the `spatstat` package, together with additional tools to ensure numerical stability, and to provide diagnostic information.

Do you really need to re-implement the procedure from scratch?

I can't see any obvious flaws in your code, but the soft-core model is very prone to numerical instability, and you said you get very large values of the sufficient staitstic, so this may be the explanation.

In `spatstat` the soft core sufficient statistic `-\sum_j d_{ij}^{-2/kappa}` is rescaled to `-\sum_j (sigma_0/d_{ij})^{2/kappa}` where `sigma_0` is a trial value estimated from the nearest-neighbour distances. This generally keeps the numerical oscillations manageable. See the help for `Softcore` in the `spatstat` package.

Comment: The reason I need to implement from scratch is because I am trying to fit an extended model where the soft-core interaction is a sub-part of the interaction of the whole model and I realized I can't even get the simple soft-core model to work. Now that you've explained it, it makes a lot more sense. Thank you very much!